# Search class based data structure like $xml.SelectNodes()

Tags: powershell, class, selectnodes

I am refactoring some functional code to use classes, and trying to understand the "best" (most performant, easiest to read, least likely to be deprecated, etc.) way to do so.
The functional code uses XML as a data structure, and I need to be able to search for nodes based on certain criteria. So, in simplified form...

```
$xml = [XML]@"
<Definitions>
    <Package id="A">
        <Task id="A.1">
            <DisplayName>Ignore</DisplayName>
        </Task>
        <Task id="A.2">
            <DisplayName>Find</DisplayName>
        </Task>
    </Package>
    <Package id="B">
        <Task id="B.1">
            <DisplayName>Ignore</DisplayName>
        </Task>
        <Task id="B.2">
            <DisplayName>Find</DisplayName>
        </Task>
        <Task id="B.3">
            <DisplayName>Ignore</DisplayName>
        </Task>
    </Package>
    <Package id="C">
        <Task id="C.1">
            <DisplayName>Ignore</DisplayName>
        </Task>
        <Task id="C.2">
            <DisplayName>Ignore</DisplayName>
        </Task>
        <Task id="C.3">
            <DisplayName>Find</DisplayName>
        </Task>
    </Package>
</Definitions>
"@

$target = 'Find'

$finds = $xml.SelectNodes("//Task/DisplayName[.='$target']")

foreach ($find in $finds) {
    Write-Host "$($find.ParentNode.id)"
}
```

I have managed to get Package and Task collections working, and I can populate a collection of Packages, containing collections of Tasks, based on the same XML, like so...

```
class Package {
    # Properties
    [String]$ID
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]$Tasks = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::New()

    # Constructor
    Package ([String]$id) {
        $this.ID = $id
    }
    # Method
    [Void] addTask([Task]$newTask) {
        $this.Tasks.Add($newTask)
    }
}

class Task {
    # Properties
    [String]$ID
    [String]$DisplayName

    # Constructor
    Task ([String]$id) {
        $this.ID = $id
    }
}

$definitions = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::New()

foreach ($package in $xml.SelectNodes("//Package")) {
    $newPackage = [Package]::New($package.ID)
    foreach ($task in $package.SelectNodes("Task")) {
        $newTask = [Task]::New($task.ID)
        $newTask.DisplayName = $task.DisplayName
        $newPackage.addTask($newTask)
    }
    $definitions.Add($newPackage)
}
```

And I can verify that is working with some foreach loops...

```
foreach ($package in $definitions) {
    Write-Host "$($package.ID)"
    foreach ($task in $package.Tasks) {
        Write-Host "  $($task.ID) $($task.DisplayName)"
    }
}
```

Now I want to replicate `$finds = $xml.SelectNodes("//Task/DisplayName[.='$target']")`, and do it the "right" way. I could just iterate through the list like this.

```
foreach ($package in $definitions) {
    foreach ($task in $package.Tasks) {
        if ($task.DisplayName -eq $target) {
            Write-Host "$($task.ID)"
        }
    }
}
```

Or I could have a Find method in the Package class that takes $target as an argument, and iterates over it's own Tasks.

But I wonder if there is some Automatic Variable that already contains all objects of a particular Type, or a way to populate a variable with all objects of a particular Type, so I am iterating over a smaller list. But then I need to be able to find the Parent, and at that point this whole line of thinking seems to break down, since there is no Parent data unless I provide it.

So, what is the best way to do this search?

Also, FWIW, the reason for this exercise is that fact that there are actually about 30 different  variations of Task that I will need to implement, with LOTS of shared behavior. Doing that in Functions has led to a bunch of redundant code and lots of work implementing new tasks or fixing bugs in the duplicated code. Inheritance will fix that, and a bunch of other issues that have come up, so moving to classes makes a lot of sense in the bigger picture.

Comment: instead of the double foreach loop you can do `$finds = ($xml.Definitions.Package.Task | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $target }).id`

Comment: @Theo, that's an improved way to do the search in XML, but what about doing the same search in the nested objects data structure?

Comment: "I want to replicate `$finds = $xml.SelectNodes("//Task/DisplayName[.='$target']")`" - why replicate it? Why not just ... use it?

Comment: Have you tried it at all? It gets all nested task ids where the displayname equals to whatever is in `$target`. That **_IS_** what you are asking isn't it??

Comment: Guys, the key is I can't do the search in the XML. I need to do the search in the objects created from the data in the XML. The bigger picture is that over time I will be deleting some of those objects, and then searching again, narrowing down where the specific target information is found until it is only found in one place. Then I will act on the last instance. The XML is used to populate the starting set of objects, then those objects are whittled down.

Comment: The ultimate use is to manage uninstall of a lot of software that has a bunch of shared components, and can be installed in a variety of mixes on different machines. Each Package represents a particular piece of software, and each Task is an Uninstall. So I go through the uninstall tasks for a package, uninstall the stuff that is unique and NOT uninstalling the shared stuff. Later I might do it again and uninstall a few more Packages. later still I uninstall theist package, so when a search for shared components shows no other uses, I can uninstall those too.

Answer (score 1):

As Theo alludes to in the comments, for a simple object hierarchy like your `Package`, you can just use `Where-Object`:

```
$package.Tasks |Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $target }
```

---

Implementing a `FindTasks()` method is therefore just a question of wrapping `Where-Object`:

```
class Package
{
  # ...

  [Task[]]
  FindTasks([scriptblock]$filter)
  {
    return $this.Tasks |Where-Object $filter
  }
}
```

After which the user can do `$package.FindTasks({$_.ID -eq $ID -or $_.DisplayName -like '*keyword*'})` or whatever else they want to filter on